# How to decide where to execute our business logic?

Tags: database, backend, software-design

As we are writing our web application we come across multiple decision regarding the execution of our business logic.

Our stack include `mongodb` database and `mongoose` on top of our nodejs powered backend.
How should we decide whether to execute a specific computation in our backend code, or build a query for the database?

Simple example: we have a collection of vehicles. We want to calculate the average number of seats.
Should we pull all of the data and compute the result in the application, or should we create a query (aggregation) for the database to execute?

Pros (execute on DB)

- faster in terms of network traffic for large collections
- probably more efficient

Cons

- coupled to the DB
- harder to test

Answer (score 0):

I would build an abstraction into the application - so something like someBusinessLayerClass.getAverageNumberOfSeats() (or whatever the equivalent syntax in Node would be).  That can then delegate the call to the database in the production system, while it can be mocked/stubbed for testing.  If you want to test it end-to-end, use an integration test.

This particular requirement, in my view, comes down to querying data - and one could argue that it's fine to give that responsibility to the database.  However, if you're implementing logic for an actual business rule (lets say you need to validate that a particular vehicle can be rented to a particular driver, based on licence category and accident history), then it should live in the business logic layer.